# Searching for patterns to create a TCP Connection Pool for high performance messaging

Tags: performance, network-programming, tcp, tcpclient

I'm creating a new Client / Server application in C# and expect to have a fairly high rate of connections. That made me think of database connection pools which help mitigate the expense of creating and disposing connections between the client and database.

I would like to create a similar capability for my application and haven't been able to find any good examples of how to apply this pattern. Do I really need to spin up an instance of a TcpClient every time I want to send a message to the server and receive a receipt message? Each connection is expected to transport between 1-5KB with each receiving a 1KB response message.

I realize this question is somewhat vague, but I am starting from scratch so I am open to suggestions. Even if that means my suppositions are all wrong.

Comment: Do you need all these connections to stay connected, or establish a new connection each time they're used? Are they all to the same server?

If it's to the same server, there might be better ways to share the same connection than create multiple connections, even if they're all connected all the time. This will probably be a lot more efficient too.

Comment: The pattern will need to support n number of clients eaching sending one message and receive one back from a central server. Any one client may have multiple concurrent connections each sending and receiving messages. This is due to background threads each collecting data and then needing to send it to the server (request/response).  Initially my thinking was to have one connection pool per client, servicing all concurrent requests for connections for that client, possibly reusing connections/sockets/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introducing connection pool is a sort of optimization. [Premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) can be bad.

I would recommend you start develpment without introducing connection pool. When client and server code is stable enough you can create load tests and detect performance problems.

Connection pool is required if time to create a connection is considerable compared to the rate at which data is coming to/from server (load tests should indicate that).

If data from client is send not that often you may not even need connection pool.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... In my case, the test data already shows that applying a connection pool is an appropriate next step.